# Trying to bind a method as a parameter in a function that will pass said bound function to another function

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

I am trying to communicate between applications with NATS.io. In order to asynchronously  get a message when a publisher pushes something to a subject, you can do

```
natsConnection_Subscribe(&subscription, connection, subjectName, callback, closure);
```

The callback parameter is a `natsMsgHandler` which essentially is a `typedef void (*natsMsgHandler)(natsConnection *nc, natsSubscription *sub, natsMsg *msg, void *closure);`

I have wrapped this logic in a class to hold the connection and subscription objects and added a wrapper method:

```
natsStatus adNatsSubAsyncWithCallback(const std::string& processName, const std::string& subName, lambda callback)
{
(...)
natsConnection_Subscribe(&sub->m_natsSubscription, nc, subName.c_str(), callback, nullptr);
(...)
}
```

Now, when I need to use this, let's say in my main, I can do:

```
    nats_interface ni1;
    ni1.adNatsSubAsyncWithCallback("onIdRequest", sendingSubj, [](natsConnection *nc,
                                                                  natsSubscription *sub,
                                                                  natsMsg *msg,
                                                                  void *closure) { *DO STUFF* });
```

My problem is that I cannot for the love of god figure out how to best approach the scenario of having the callback be a method of a class.

Let's say I have a class

```
class test1
{
  public:
    void onIdRequest(natsConnection *nc, natsSubscription *sub, natsMsg *msg, void *closure) const {
        natsMsg_Destroy(msg);
    }
}
```

If I try something like

```
    test1 t1;
    auto temp = [t1](natsConnection *nc,
                     natsSubscription *sub,
                     natsMsg *msg,
                     void *closure) {
        t1.onIdRequest(nc, sub, msg, closure);
    };
```

and pass temp to the function call instead of a lambda directly, I get an error.

I also kind of tried to std::bind a method of class test1 with a matching definition to `natsMsgHandler` and pass that function<> object instead with absolutely catastrophic results.

How would I implement something like this?

EDIT:

The bind attempt was like this:

```
    auto callback = std::bind(&test1::onIdRequest,&t1,_1,_2,_3,_4);
    ni1.adNatsSubAsyncWithCallback("onIdRequest", sendingSubj, callback);
```

Comment: This is what the last parameter of `natsConnection_Subscribe` is for

Comment: How do you mean? Nullptr to the callback and lambda in the closure?

Comment: `and pass temp to the function call instead of a lambda directly, I get an error.` What's the error message? Seems your approach is applicable.